# Error view Index.cshtml not found for ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app when build on Azure build agent

Tags: azure-devops, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I get an error "View Index.cshtml not found" for my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app when building it on Azure build agent, but when building locally, it is working fine.

I tried same command which is executed on build agent still could not get the issue. Tried several code changes to fix this issue but still no clues. Searched on net even on stackoverflow but sadly no solution works.

Please someone help me out.

I am using following input in pipeline.yaml:

```
      solution: 'src/Indl.Web.Core.sln'
      msbuildArgs: '/property:OutDir="$(BUILD.BINARIESDIRECTORY)"\x64\ /p:RunWixToolsOutOfProc=true /p:PackageVersion=$(GitVersion.SemVer) /p:SASigning=true /p:SACertificate=prod.prot /p:PackageOutputPath="$(BUILD.BINARIESDIRECTORY)"\x64\'
      platform: 'x64'
      vsVersion: '16.0'
      configuration: 'Release'
      clean: true
      msbuildArchitecture: 'x64
```

The solution has one more mvc app which is working as expected.
I cross verified dll and found that the section 'AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument' is not available in dll which is usually has all view related information.

Comment: Any community member could not interesting to resolve my issue, Is it like I posted my question in wrong forum, can someone suggest better forum name....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use following command in pipeline.yaml
hope it should work.

```
solution: 'src/Indl.Web.Core.sln'
  msbuildArgs: '/property:OutDir="$(BUILD.BINARIESDIRECTORY)"\x64\ /p:RunWixToolsOutOfProc=true /p:PackageVersion=$(GitVersion.SemVer) /p:SASigning=true /p:SACertificate=prod.prot /p:PackageOutputPath="$(BUILD.BINARIESDIRECTORY)"\x64\'
  platform: 'x64'
  vsVersion: '17.0'
  configuration: 'Release'
  clean: true
  msbuildArchitecture: 'x64
```

Actually you used vsVersion of vs 2019(16.0) but since you are compiling .Net 6.0 which is fully supported in vs 2022(17.0)

Comment: Thanks for your response, Yes I was building locally in vs2022, I will implement your this suggestion. let see if it works.

Answer (score 14):

I've experienced the same Issue few days ago. I suspect that the problem is related to the update to .net 6.0.2.

It seems like, that with the update the Packages '"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilers' and 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset' are missing.

After adding the following lines to all Projects containg .cshtml/.html files everything worked as excpected and the files are available under AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument in the DLLs.

```yaml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilers" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset" Version="4.1.0">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

**Edit 17.5.2023**

We have experienced this issue today again.

Following solution worked for us:

- Add `Mirosoft.AspNetCore.App` as Frameworkreference

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

- Remove the above mentioned PackageReferences

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! The original post was describing the very same symptom that I was having, but I was already specifying the use of MSBuild version 17.0, so nothing to gain from the accepted answer.

But by just adding the two NuGet packages you suggested, it started working.
What led you on to discover that?

Comment: I have just spent 8 hrs trying to work out why my CICD pipeline was broken.  This was the answer. I would NEVER have worked this out.  Bene Schmaler you are a total legend in my mind!  I have absolutely no idea how you worked this out. Great job and a thousand thank yous.

Comment: One of my colleagues found on the server-logs that the assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis' could no be found. After a bit of searching we found the missing packages. 
We think, that maybe somewhere on the "Buildtree" in .net 6.0.2 the `PrivateAssets` changed to all, and that's why is not delivered by default anymore. 
So we should give props to my colleagues as well :D

Comment: Has anyone told Microsoft about this?  I suspect that in the next few days, many more people will come down this same dark alley.

Comment: I've created one right now: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7221

Comment: Amazing man. Thanks. This saved my googling 2 days straight

Comment: After experiencing new problems with this, wrote about my experience in the .NET Core issue that was created for this: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/23972#issuecomment-1671647249

Comment: I've seen the need for adding an additional comment in the aforementioned .NET Core issue, as I found that it matters which MSBuild version you're using in your build pipeline: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/23972#issuecomment-1676941313